# Sonar - Error when upgrading to sonar 3.5.1

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to upgrade Sonar 3.3.2 to Sonar 3.5.1 and getting this error: Fail to request server version.  When I had the same error with version 3.3.2, it usually happened when the sonar server was down.  But now sonar 3.5.1 is up but I can't run analysis with Sonar Ant Task.  I am using sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar.  I also included property "sonar.forceAuthentication" and set it to "false".  I think that the Anyone group is granted a User role on the projest by default.  Has anyone seen this problem before?  Are there any additional properties I need to include?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does that happen all the time or only on existing projects? (i.e. if you analyse a new project, do you get the same error)

Comment: I get the same error all the time - for new and existing projects.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to paste the log that you get?

Comment: I tried again and it worked only on new projects.  Is there a way to make it work on existing projects?

Comment: Also sonar 3.5.1 works only with version 2.0 of sonar-ant-task jar for me.  When I use version 2.1 of sonar-ant-task, I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server version.
Any ideas?